# Flexbox: inline as html attributes or as CSS classes?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Flex box "inlined" as html attributes: [(sample taken from LumX website)](http://ui.lumapps.com/directives/text-fields):

```
<div flex-container="row">
    <div flex-item>
        <lx-text-field label="Company" disabled="true">
            <input type="text" ng-model="textFields.disabled" ng-disabled="true">
        </lx-text-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or as CSS attributes:

```
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
```

What is the recommended way to use flexbox? As css classes or as html attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a somewhat subjective/relative question, as it might be a little a matter of preferences. That said, this is the **first time** I see inline Flexbox; all of the posts, tutorials, etc., I have seen on Flexbox have been made using CSS attributes.

It seems that the common practice is using CSS. Two reasons I come up with for doing so:

- **Separation of concerns**: Inline CSS is usually discouraged because it messes content (HTML) with presentation (CSS). Separating them, makes it easier to maintain and modify the site.
- **Custom changes**: You might need, for example, to use different layouts depending on the screen size (with *media queries*) or you might need to use vendor prefixes for browsers' support. In both cases, that would be better done with separate CSS code than with inline HTML.